# Battery backup with single diode

Tags: power

Below is the circuit for backup power from BAT2 when BAT1 is missing. *BAT1 in my case is the LD1117 regulator.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO8lTi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Suppose only two situations are possible: (1) BAT1 and BAT2 both exists, (2) BAT1 missing. Can I exclude D2?

UPD. "BAT1 missing" mean LD1117 still exists in the circuit, but its input voltage missing.

Comment: Will BAT1 actually be removed from the circuit, or just unpowered since its an LD1117?

Comment: @KrisBahnsen: I've updated my question.

Comment: As well as what wouter said, if the the LM1117 has a voltage setting resistive divider this will draw current from  BAT2. 
|| Why do you wish to eliminate D2? Voltage drop or other reason?. If voltage drop is the issue then a MOSFET can be arranged to produce minimal drop when on but still block correctly.

Comment: @Russell: Yes, diode dropout is 0,6V -- too many for my voltages (3V). Can I use MOSFET with this small voltages?

Comment: Yes - as long as you can trigger the MOSFET on when you want it to conduct and off when conduction is not wanted then you can use a MOSFET. This is not hard but may need a little thinking to ensure all possible conditions are met. A MOSFET drops Iload x Rdson. Rdson is FET on resistance and can be a few milliOhms if desired. Usually something around 100 milliOhms will be adequate and cheap.  Note that the reverse body diode across FET Drain-Source in most MOSFETs means it will always conduct in the reverse direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you exclude the diode and you do not provide input power to the LM1117 it will (at least potentially) experience a reverse voltage (output higher than input). The 7805 regulator can be damaged by such a situation, but I have not heard of similar effects on an LM1117. But it is still outside its normal mode of operation, so I would advise against it.